# commandtype on other side not populating

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlcommand

I have following sql code to execute sp in dot net,im using visual studio 2012,

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_TocheckExistingRecord";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

but whenever i write CommandType on right hand side it shows me error commandtype doesnot exist in the current context..but its populating on lefthand side in intellisense ..plz help me..why this error is coming

Comment: Have you tried with full name like `System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure` ?

Comment: I have import system.data and this issue is solved.thanks @Soner Gönül

Comment: pressing `ctrl`+`.` on the word that is giving error will show you a list containing which namespace you need to import.